# node.js + express + socket.io cannot load javascript files into index.html

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-status-code-404, server

I'm developing an application and the server is currently set up and working well.

This is the index.html that shows when you access the server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I get a 404 error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" when importing those javascript files, which are in the same directory.

Here is my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html'); // DO I NEED TO SEND THE OTHER FILES HERE ASWELL?
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with `src="client.js"` instead of `src="./client.js"`? Far shot, but might solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried that aswell.

Comment: Hmm then I suppose your resources are not exposed through the application, in which case you will have to make them accessible in a simliar manner to res.sendFile(). There is a way to expose a whole directory for example, but can't remember exactly how.

Comment: As it stands right now the server will only transfer the contents of index.html when the page is acessed, nothing else. The thing you might be  looking for is express.static

Comment: What do you mean by express.static?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in

Comment: I don't get this totally. Is this a new module I need to install or a property of express, that I'm already using? I'm really a beginner at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the HTML file is located in the same path as the scripts are, then use relative path like `src = "main.js"`. If it still doesn't work, maybe it's Express' fault.

Add the codes below into your `app.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
```

And the scripts can be accessed from the path relative to `/scripts`- *e.g.* `main.js` from `http://yourdomain/script.js` but not from `http://yourdomain/scripts/main.js`.
Sorry for my English.