# How can i set Socket.io scripts outside the index, the documentation shows an example but puts the script inside the index file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

This is the code shown in the example

Server.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
```

i'd like to have something like this on my HTML file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/client.js"></script>
```

If anyone has any idea how to achieve this im open on tips and advice, im new to socket.io THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: So, you create client.js and put it in the right spot on your server and then create an express route for it so your web server will serve it when requested - probably using `express.static()`.  What part of that do you not understand?  FYI, you should probably change to `<script src="/js/client.js"></script>` so it isn't dependent upon the path of the page it's in.

Comment: Thanks, i wasnt able to figure out how express works but i made it work by adding: `var express = require('express');` so this way using express as a variable i could add `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));`

Comment: I found the solution for my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124332/node-js-express-socket-io-cannot-load-javascript-files-into-index-html